# if no width is specified, where do padding inherit length

Tags: html, css, padding

I want to know how many pixels are there in the code whenever I'm using em and percentage. EM is using the default browser font-size and can be over written, and it does inherit the parent block.

However, when I use the percent, I can't figure out how many is the exact pixels.

According to w3.org

> Percentages:      refer to width of containing block

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#padding-properties

If I don't specify the width of its containing block, where does it refer. check this. https://jsfiddle.net/jameslem/2fygk5bq/

```
    <style>
    html{
    font-size: 20px;
}
.small{
    font-size:200%;
    padding: .5em;
}

.big{
    font-size:.5em;
    padding: 10%;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}
</style>
<body>
    <p class="small"> 
    LOVE <!-- font-size in px is 40 and padding is 20px --> 
        <span class="big">LETTER</span> <!-- font size is 20px and I want to know how many pixel is 10% padding-->
    </p>

</body>
```

Does my screen resolution matters? I mean If I have 1360 x 768, does my width 1360px is also the base where the percents gets its percentage?

Comment: The resolution definitely matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When setting padding, if you use percentages, it calculates the amount by multiplying against the width of the parent container. But if you set padding using em units, it multiplies against container's font size.

Your `.small` container has a padding of .5em, which is calculated as .5em of the current font-size set for that container. In other words, it's .5em of 20px (base font) * 200% (font-size setting in `.small`).

But `.big` has a padding of 10%. Its parent container is `p.small` which is defaulting to 100% of the available body. Therefore, the padding of `.big` is 10% of the available body width.

If you need to find out the exact pixels of the padding after the CSS rules have been applied, you could use JavaScript. The device resolution, client font-size settings, and browser all may effect pixel sizes when dealing with relative units.